# web element resize cuts height but properly resizes width?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a cascade of div elements based on wcDocker with the last being a table bigger than screen size. The width is always displayed properly and resized properly ("width: 100%"), but the height when set to 100% cuts of the bottom and doesn't display a slider, when set to explicit (e.g. 500px), then is displayed properly with slides, but is cut off when resized below 500px.

I'd like to have the table height use the full available size, display a slider and resize automatically without me overloading any "resized" event - as the "width" does. "overflow" is set to "auto".

This is a complex project with lots of libraries and css layers, would anyone know which css tag would make "width" and "height" behave in such a different manner?

As suggested in comments I managed to reproduce it with relatively minimal code (not sure how long the link below will last):
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GOVQIVTEJ3HY

As one can check with the example resizing a window nicely deal with width (showing properly horizontal slide, and most importantly showing vertical slide when needed), however height is sometimes cut off and the horizontal slide disappears.

Any suggestion and a research direction would be welcomed, sorry if something trivial.

In case the above link expires below is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.ex1 {
   background-color: lightblue;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   display: block;
}

body.ex2 {
   overflow: hidden;
}

div.box {
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   min-width: 300px;
}

span.long {
   min-width: 600px;
   display: inline-block;
}

</style>
</head>
<body class="ex2">

<h1>The overflow Property</h1>

<p>The overflow property specifies whether to clip content or to add scrollbars when an element's content is too big to fit in a specified area.</p>

<h2>overflow: scroll:</h2>
<div class="ex1">
<div class="box">
<span class="long">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
</span>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: either share a minimal code which replicates the issue, or share the link of the page where the issue exists. Also the problem statement is not very clear.

Comment: Thank you, the question has been updated with more details.